# Is the subadditivity of quantum entropy valid in the infinite-dimensional case?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-computer

Does the subadditivity (and [strong subadditivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Subadditivity_of_Quantum_Entropy)) of quantum entropy hold for infinite dimensional quantum systems as well? Unfortunately the books in my hand give proof for finite dimensional cases only and I could not extend them to infinite dimensional cases. Please give some reference or some outline of approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true quite generally (for seperable Hilbert spaces at least). The original proof is in "Proof of the Strong Subadditivity of Quantum Mechanichal Entropy", by Lieb and Ruskai (J. Math. Phys. 14, 1938–1941 (1973)). The main idea is to prove the finite-dimensional case, and then extend it by taking a limit of the inequality on finite-dimensional subspaces (which is why seperability is needed).